# Why is git showing text file as binary file?

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8

I have `A.cpp` file on source repository on two different branches. `A.cpp` is simple text file containing c++ code on Branch Parent with encode as `UTF-8`. While on branch child A.cpp is encoded in `UCS-2 LE BOM`. Now, If I merge child branch into Parent. **Git gives warning cannot merge binary files**. If I convert encoding to `UTF-8` on Child Branch and commit the changes(i.e. On Child Branch File encoding is UTF-8). Even though file having same encoding on repository if I merge it gives same warning. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: what does `file -i A.cpp` output in the two branches?

Comment: I am using git on windows and if i run above command it gives error. Command not found.

Comment: Four years ago and no answers?